# A question from an old french olympiad

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've found an exercice that I've no clue to do it, I expose it to you

> Let suppose we have a family of $1789$ integers which sum is equal to zero. Show that the sum of their $37$th power is a multiple of $399$.

Any hint or solution ?

Comment: Hint:  look up the [Carmichael Lambda Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) and compute $\lambda (399)$

Comment: @lulu $\lambda (399) = 18$, as calculated in https://comnuan.com/cmnn02/cmnn02006/cmnn02006.php

Now, how does it help to solve the problem?

Comment: @SARTHAKGUPTA  Well, since $\lambda(399)=18$ we have that $a^{36}\equiv \pmod {399}=1$ if $\gcd(399,a)=1$.    Thus for those $a$ we have $a^{37}\equiv a \pmod {399}$.  Now just check $2,3,19$ separately.